How to create and approval process for both manager and segment head in a single approval process
I need help creating an approval process involving both the manager and the segment head. The first step of the approval requires the approval of the manager, It should go to the approval of the segment head only when the manager has approved.
I have already added the manager and segment head in the user details section under profiles. The manager and segment head will be different for each profile.
When setting up the approval process, I could fetch the manager without any issues, but I couldn't find an option to include the segment head in the approval process.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know the steps I should follow to include both roles in the approval process? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
